# Exception not been handled in Android

Tags: java, android, exception

Below are some lines of code

```
 @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
public static Location getLocation() throws LocationNotFoundException{
    mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(myActivity, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if(location!=null) {
                        mLocation = location;
                    }
                    else {
                        throw new LocationNotFoundException();
                    }
                }
            });
    return mLocation;
}
```

Now, `LocationNotFoundException` is a custom exception, extending the `Exception` class. The line where I throw the custom exception, I am getting an error stating that the `LocationNotFoundException` is unhandled, even though I am letting the exception travel down the call stack using the `throws` keyword, and I am handling the exception at the point from where the particular method is called, using a try/catch block.

Here is where I handle the exception.

```
 try {
        mLocation =  LocationUtil.getLocation();

    } catch (LocationNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location Not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check that your custom LocationNotFoundException is not conflicting with another exception with the same name but different package

Comment: @MatPag No, there seems to be no exception named LocationNotFoundException

Answer (score 3):

The exception is thrown in a different scope than you expect.
It is thrown in the scope of the `onSuccess` method of an anonymous inner class.
You cannot propagate this exception from the `getLocation` method,
because the exception will not be thrown during the invocation of `getLocation`,
but at a later time when the success listener is actually used.

Also note that by the contract of the `OnSuccessListener` interface,
the `onSuccess` method cannot throw exceptions.
You need to handle exceptions in your implementation of this method.

Comment: @AshwinKumar if this answered your question, then perhaps you can [mark it accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

That is because OnSuccessListener's method onSuccess neither declares your exception in `throws` section nor it handles it with a `catch` block. That is why the code won't compile.